# Cookie from API on different domain that I control

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, cross-domain, jwt

I'm implementing login functionality on my site and I'm running into some problems when sending jwt tokens as cookies.

When the user logs in on the frontend, a POST request is sent with "credentials: 'include'" (I'm using fetch) to my backend API, which returns a jwt token if the login was successful. This all works fine, and I can see the cookie in chrome dev tools, and performing actions that require authentication work fine.

However, when I refresh the site, the jwt cookies disappear. I have ruled out errors with expiration. Through experimentation I've figured out that the domain is the problem. The cookie's domain is "127.0.0.1" from the locally hosted instance of the API, which is different than the domain of the locally hosted website. If I manually change the domain of the cookie to the same as the website, the cookie doesn't disappear.

But that does not solve my problem permanently, as the backend API is hosted on a different domain than the frontend. I've been reading up on cross-domain requests but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I control both the frontend and the backend, but I'm starting to wonder if I might be going about this the wrong way? Would the simplest solution be to host my api on, say 'api.mydomain.com' instead?